# Pasar metodo como Parametro dentro de otro metodo

Tags: java, programación-funcional

Tengo una duda, intento pasar un método, como parámetro en otro método, Ejemplo:
""

```
PonerEscuchar(botonCerrar, funcionCerrar());

public static void funcionCerrar() {
     System.exit(0);
   }

public  void PonerEscuchar(JButton boton, Object object) {
    boton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {     
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {       
        ¿?
      }      
    });
  }
```

""

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes realizar de la siguiente manera:

```
private void ponerEscuchar(JButton boton, Runnable miMetodo) {
    boton.addActionListener(e -> miMetodo.run());
}
```

En este caso como podrás observar te ahorras mucho del código de las clases internas ya que la mayoría como en este caso son interfaces funcionales.

para llamar tu método, pásale la referencia:

```
this.ponerEscuchar(this.jButton1, this::funcionCerrar);
```

Si usas paréntesis como lo harías normalmente lo ejecutarás y eso no e slo que quieres.

Al definir el parámetro como runnable le estamos diciendo que va a recibir algo cuyo método regresa void y que no recibe parámetros, y una vez más nos ahorramos todo el *boilerplate* que conllevaría escribir un Runnable.

Te he escrito un artículo para que aprendas allí los conceptos necesarios y tus opciones al [pasar un método como parámetro](https://javapro.org/programming-languages/java-pasar-un-metodo-como-parametro/).

Mi código con toda la demostración es el siguiente:

```
package org.javapro.preguntas.stackoverflow.question605767;

import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import javax.swing.JButton;

/**
 * @author scher
 */
public class CerrarBotonListener extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public static void funcionCerrar() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public boolean isTechnicalFighter(String name) {
        return switch (name) {
            case "El Santo" -> true;
            case "El cavernario" -> false;
            case "El bulldog" -> false;
            default -> false;
        };
    }

    private void ponerEscuchar(JButton boton, Runnable miMetodo) {
        boton.addActionListener(e -> miMetodo.run());
    }

    public boolean isTechnical(String nombreLuchador, Predicate<String> predicate) {
        return predicate.test(nombreLuchador);
    }

    public JButton creaBoton(String texto) {
        return new JButton(texto);
    }

    /**
     * Creates new form CerrarBotonListener
     */
    public CerrarBotonListener() {
        initComponents();
        this.ponerEscuchar(this.jButton1, CerrarBotonListener::funcionCerrar);
        this.isTechnical("El Santo", this::isTechnicalFighter);
        this.creacion("Cerrar", this::creaBoton);
        this.imprimeNumeroDeLaSuerte(this::numeroDeLASuerte);
    }

    private void imprimeNumeroDeLaSuerte(Supplier<Integer> numeroDeLASuerte) {
        System.out.println(numeroDeLASuerte.get());
    }

    public int numeroDeLASuerte() {
        return (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    }

    private void creacion(String textoBotón, Function<String, JButton> creaBoton) {
        creaBoton.apply(textoBotón);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {
        java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        jButton1.setText("Cerrar");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(115, 160, 162, 168);
        getContentPane().add(jButton1, gridBagConstraints);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CerrarBotonListener.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CerrarBotonListener.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CerrarBotonListener.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CerrarBotonListener.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new CerrarBotonListener().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```